# firestore how to check for the doc owner before write?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, rules

How do I check the document owner before allow for the user the create ?
steps:

1. the document is already created by the same owner.
2. after that the same owner will try to create property and value inside the doc.

`document.owner` give me error when publishing.

```
//only allow create in moviesCommentID/{document} when document is owned by the user
match /moviesCommentID/{document=**} {
    allow create: if request.auth != null && document.owner == request.auth.uid;
}
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1- Creation**

You need to have a field in the `Firestore` Document you are changing that stores the owner uid

```
allow create: if request.auth != null && resource.data.ownerUid == request.auth.uid;
```

**2- Update:**

Use the same as for "create" (owner is actually the person logged), but also add something to say they cant change the owner to another user

```
allow update: if request.resource.data.ownerUid== resource.data.ownerUid;
```

Note that `request.resource` variable contains the future state of the document

Comment: In your first part, how can you access `resource.data.ownerUid` if the document is only about to get created? Shouldn't it be `request.resource.data.ownerUid` instead?

Comment: @KonstantinKozirev Good point !!! In my opinion, part 1 of his question was specifically on how to make sure the document **already exists**... that's why I recommended `resource.data.ownerUid`... But if we want to allow the creation of a new document, then you are correct with `request.resource.data.ownerUid`

Answer (score 2):

The `document` variable in your rules is a string with the document ID as its value.

Firestore doesn't have any built-in concept of a document owner. But if you have an `owner` field in the document's data, you can access that in your rules as `resource.data.owner`. Also check the Firebase documentation on [data validation in security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation).